# How do I run multiple ruby files simultaneously without them stepping on each other?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I need to run several rb files simultaneously. Each file is setup identically (simplified sample below)

File #1 (there are 6 of these total with about 10 tests each)

```
require_relative './spec_helper'
require_relative './tests'

    config.before(:each) do
        @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
        @base_url = get_url
    end  

    config.after(:each) do
        @driver.close
    end  

RSpec.describe 'File 1' do

  it 'test 1' do
       login
       verify element present
       logout
  end

  it 'test 2' do
       login
       verify element present
       logout
  end

   it 'test 3' do
       login
       verify element present
       logout
   end

end
```

All the files run great separately - however when run simultaneously they end up stepping on each other during the after hook specifically @driver.close and I get the following error:

An error occurred in an after hook NoMethodError: undefined method quit' for nil:NilClass
    occurred at C:/Automated_Testing/Indie/w_molap_1.rb:31:inblock (2 levels) in '

My question is: is there something different I could do - perhaps in the driver before hook setup that will allow me to run these files at the same time without them stepping on each other?

Comment: How do you run them at the same time? The method of execution may affect your options.

Comment: @Jesper -  I do it one of two ways -  each set of ten tests is it's own .rb file, I can literally just highlight them all and hit 'enter' and they all start going. Or my preferred way, is that I'm using a batch file to call each of the rb files simultaneously - it waits for them all to finish them emails me a log of the console output.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to look into is using the Ruby Gem for `parallel_test` .  Also, you should extend your test class from Test::Unit::TestCase  so that you can take advantage of defining setup/teardown methods.   Also, each test method should be separated into separate test class for each one so that the parallel_test can run each one in a separate thread.

Also, I would keep it simple in the beginning and don't use RSpec (as a BDD framework) until you have the basic multi-threading figured out.